# How to run an application continuously in server

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server edition.
I have access to the server via ssh.

My question is how can I run a program through SSH such that it wont be get closed even if I disconnect the ssh. It has to be run in the server as a service.

can you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke command with `nohup`

from `nohup` info:

> 'nohup' runs the given COMMAND with hangup signals ignored, so that the
>   command can continue running in the background after you log out.
>   Synopsis:
>
> ```
>  nohup COMMAND [ARG]...
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To run program as service i suggest to use

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --chuid $USER --chdir $DIR -- $DAEMON_ARGS
```

take a look in `/etc/init.d/skeleton` and write init script based on this example.

Answer (score 2):

nohup does not automatically put the command it runs in the background, you should end the command line with an & symbol.

nohup command &

Comment: also u can press ctrl+Z, then bg

Answer (score 2):

[Upstart](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)!  As you're using Ubuntu 12.04..

You create an upstart script in `/etc/init/`

Your script contains directives, which control the process, how it runs, where it runs, environment, respawn if fail, etc.

```
# my upstart script
# optional stuff
description "start and stop the THING"
version "1.0"
author "Tom"


# configuration variables.
# You'll want to change these as needed
env A_THING_TO_SET=blaaah

# tell upstart we're creating a daemon
# upstart manages PID creation for you.
expect fork
# of course, if it doesn't fork, take out the above line

script
# My startup script, plain old shell scripting here.
chdir /opt/thingy/bin
exec /opt/thingy/bin/thingy ARGUMENTS
# create a custom event in case we want to chain later
emit thingy_running
end script
```

Taken and adapted from: http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/

I also recommend you read the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

If you're not using Ubuntu, then other options include [supervisor(d)](http://supervisord.org/), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)
all of which suck far less than running stuff in screen or with nohup.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the nohup advice, consider using [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), it allows you to have mutliple terminal windows open with the ability to resume connections should your ssh session die for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

**screen**  is useful.

Run screen, then run your command, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>d</kbd>. You can return to your program. Run  `screen -ls` to find *Detached* screen, connect to it with `screen -r 20673.pts-0.srv`.